# byte string issue after porting application from python2.7 to python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, porting

I ported my application from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7. After porting, I am facing this issue. My strings 'string is in bytes' is converted to b'string is in bytes'. I need to place this code everywhere:

```
if (isinstance(secret_val, bytes)):
     secret_val = secret_val.decode()

if (isinstance(response_data, str)):
     response_data = str.encode(response_data)
```

I understand that there is a change in string format in python 3.7. What could be the reason for this?

This is Python 2.7 code:

---

```
if isinstance(secret_val, bytes):
        print("{0} is bytes", secret_val)
    else:
        print("{0} is not bytes", secret_val)
    log.info('save_secret:: saving in vault: secret_val:: str ' + str(secret_val))
```

---

output:

('{0} is bytes', 'VIjzLQfdLHQqF+LPPVDlj5uFA/ODFKfL9KQCfIufbRvAGXjS')

2019-08-05 08:38:30,351 - 34(uWSGIWorker5Core0) - INFO - cred_service.save_secret(108) - save_secret:: saving in vault: secret_val:: str VIjzLQfdLHQqF+LPPVDlj5uFA/ODFKfL9KQCfIufbRvAGXjS

NOTE: Bytes string appear just like a string

This is Python 3.7 code:

---

```
    log.info('save_secret:: saving in vault: secret_val:: str ' + str(secret_val))
```

---

output:

2019-08-05 07:36:14,324 - 39(b'uWSGIWorker5Core0') - INFO - cred_service.save_secret(104) - save_secret:: saving in vault: secret_val:: str b'U5OzxNNtnbOPBOMKBieVXU3DMPMGzFm8KensdSs+zOS+vh3R'

NOTE: Bytes string appear with b'string'

The below line is failing in Python 3.7, as data contains secret_val which is bytes:

```
payload = json.dumps(data)
```

TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

To get rid of this error, I need to do:

---

```
if isinstance(secret_val, bytes):
        print("{0} is bytes", secret_val)
```

---

However, the same line works fine in python 2.7, it also contains bytes.

How to handle this case ?

My application is a credential service and it contains byte string in many of the values.

Do I have to check everywhere, if its bytes perform decode else continue ?

Is there any other option available ?

Comment: The "What’s New In Python 3.0" docs contains a section for this: [Text Vs. Data Instead Of Unicode Vs. 8-bit](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)

Comment: Hope, I have asked my question in a better way with code.

Comment: @Malar Kandasamy yes, good-luck with the answer